# PowerMock ExpectNew creating real objects instead of mocked Ones

Tags: powermock, easymock, powermockrunner

```
public  class PersistenceManager {

    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        UserPersistor userPersistor = new UserPersistor(user) {

            @Override
            void somemethod() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
        };
        userPersistor.addUser();
        System.out.println("PersistenceManager added user ");
        return true;
    }
    
    
    class User {
        
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        
        
        public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
            super();
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }       
    }
    
    abstract class UserPersistor {
        
        public UserPersistor( ) {
            
        }
        public UserPersistor(User user) {
            
        }
        public void addUser() {
            System.err.println("UserPersistor added user ");
        }
        abstract void somemethod();
    }
}   

import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.expectNew;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.expectLastCall;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( PersistenceManager.class )
public class PersistenceManagerTest {
    
    private User user = null;
    
    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        
        user = createMock(User.class);      
        UserPersistor userPersistor = createMock(UserPersistor.class);
        userPersistor.addUser();
        expectLastCall();
        
        expectNew(UserPersistor.class, user).andReturn(userPersistor);      

        PowerMock.replayAll();
    }
    @Test
    public void testaddUser() {

        PersistenceManager tested = new PersistenceManager();
        tested.addUser(user);
        PowerMock.verifyAll();
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with above code? I dont see mocked object for UserPersistor. Meaning, i dont want to see "UserPersistor added user " printed. It should not do anything. But it is printing it since real object of UserPersistor is created. I am facing this problem in my actual project, thought would simulate and try to solve in a much smaller context. But I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not expecting to instantiate `UserPersistor` but an anonymous inner class extending `UserPersistor`.

To do that you need to retrieve that class, mock it and expect it. PowerMock has a `Whitebox` class to do that. You are exposing the class implementation when using it. I would recommend that you refactor your code to inject the code instead. But if you really want to, you should write this:

```
@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    user = createMock(PersistenceManager.User.class);

    Class<Object> clazz = Whitebox.getAnonymousInnerClassType(PersistenceManager.class, 1);
    PersistenceManager.UserPersistor userPersistor = createMock(clazz);
    userPersistor.addUser();

    expectNew(clazz, user).andReturn(userPersistor);

    PowerMock.replayAll();
}
```